# What's the centered fluffy art piece called in an article?

Tags: typography, style-identification, terminology, symbols

[image: thing]

I know this, but I can't recollect at all.

What is this thing called?

They are usually centered in a book or writing and I'm certain they have a name but I can't remember for the life of me. They also come in all shapes, colors and sizes.

Comment: The style of image is called a "flourish", though, I don't know what it may be called in terms of an article or book. Maybe a "flourish separator"?

Comment: well, that's... _Decoration_ or decorative separator / divider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Flourish**, **Filigree**, or **Ornament** are common terms.

Usage doesn't generally change the name. Simply because it's been used by the book designer to separate content, there's no special term I'm aware of for that specific type of usage.

Comment: Thank you very much. Filigree is what I think I had heard it called, that sounds familiar. Very grateful.

Answer (score 8):

These kinds of ornaments can also sometimes be called **[fleurons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography))**. A set of them is [included in the Wingdings typeface](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/62163/8708) with different transformations to allow for easy symmetrical decorations.

## [image: spacer] ☙ ❧

There are some fleurons available in the Unicode specification under the [Dingbats block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf) (PDF).

> #### Fleurons
>
> - 273E ✾ SIX PETALLED BLACK AND WHITE FLORETTE
> - 273F ✿ BLACK FLORETTE
> - 2740 ❀ WHITE FLORETTE
>
>   - → 1F3F5   rosette
>   - → 1F4AE   white flower
> - 2741 ❁ EIGHT PETALLED OUTLINED BLACK FLORETTE
>
>   - → 1F3F6   black rosette
> - 2766 ❦ FLORAL HEART
>
>   - = Aldus leaf
> - 2767 ❧ ROTATED FLORAL HEART BULLET
>
>   - = hedera, ivy leaf
>   - → 2619 ☙  reversed rotated floral heart bullet
>   - → 1F65B   south east pointing vine leaf

Many of the other Wingdings fleurons were recently added to the Unicode specification under the [Ornamental Dingbats](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F650.pdf) (PDF) block.

> #### Fleurons
>
> Fleurons are leaf or floral-shaped ornaments used for text decoration.
>   [image: Unicode Fleurons]

<sup>Screenshot of text because most of those glyphs are not yet supported (in my browser anyway)</sup>