# What are the symmetry-in-pair symbols usually appear in Wingdings fonts?

Tags: typography, terminology, typefaces, style-identification, symbols

For example, in Wingdings font:
[image: image description]

What are the symbols in boxes used for?

I have checked the wiki pages of [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings), [List of symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_symbols), [Ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_symbols) and [Unicode/List of useful symbols](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/List_of_useful_symbols), but I can't find what I want.

Comment: Did you know you can reverse search an image in Google images? That might yield some results. My first hunch is that these are just decorative elements without a specific meaning, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're [typographic ornaments](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19087/8708). The Wikipedia article on [fleurons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)) offers a good explanation of their use.

> A fleuron is a typographic element, or glyph, used either as a
>   punctuation mark or as an ornament for typographic compositions.
>   Fleurons are stylized forms of flowers or leaves. Robert Bringhurst in
>   The Elements of Typographic Style calls the forms "horticultural
>   dingbats." It is also known as a printers' flower, or more formally
>   as an aldus leaf hedera leaf, or simply hedera (ivy leaf) symbol.

There are [names assigned to all Wingdings symbols](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/athena/share/ghostscript/8.64/Resource/Encoding/Wingdings), here are the ones you've highlighted (one from each set for the sake of brevity):

- [image: budleafne] budleafne
- [image: vineleafboldne] vineleafboldne
- [image: Wingdings quiltsquare2]  quiltsquare2
- [image: Wingdings leafccwsw] leafccwsw

They are included in the [Ornamental Dingbats Unicode block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F650.pdf) (PDF) and described slightly differently there.

- [NORTH EAST POINTING BUD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f662/index.htm)
- [HEAVY NORTH EAST POINTING VINE LEAF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F65E/index.htm)
- [SOLID QUILT SQUARE ORNAMENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F66A/index.htm)
- [TURNED SOUTH WEST POINTING LEAF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F655/index.htm)

Comment: How to use it as a punctuation marks?

Comment: @Ooker see [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19085/8708) for an example. They can be used to denote [section breaks](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/40379).

Comment: You don’t use them as regular punctuation (you wouldn’t, for instance, use ❦ instead of a comma); but you can use them in much the same way as pilcrow signs or variously sized dots/circles are frequently used, to separate inline lists: “Members present : : Mr. Smith ❁ Mr. Anderson ❁ Mr. Weaving ❁ Mr. Reeves”, for instance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet looks like the ones for that required to have *self-symmetry* and kind of pretty like flowers. I'm not sure if the first symbol in your comment can be used in such cases.

Comment: @Ooker I don’t quite understand what you mean, but I don’t think the symmetry of the ones you’ve singled out has any real significance. They’re simply used as ornaments, and sometimes it looks prettier if there are two ornaments pointing in different directions. There’s no special name or usage for the symmetric part of it, that’s just to make them more flexible.

Comment: @Ooker [that symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2766/index.htm) has symmetrical siblings as well: ☙ ❦ ❧